# Possible malfunction - Python

Tags: python, security, boolean-logic

Is it possible for potential user to make this statement true?

```
secret = 25134231
z = ast.literal_eval(user_input)
if z == secret:
     access.granted()
```

Comment: Not really enough information here to be 100% sure, but if `user_input` is coming from something like `input()` then yes, `z == secret` can evaluate to `True`

Comment: @Jkdc If it's not a big problem for you could you please provide me with example of such evaluation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to more answer your question... I think you're getting at making function calls from user input (among other things)  through `literal_eval()`, and the answer is no, it cannot be done. `literal_eval()` is specifically designed to protect against this type of input.

For contrast see below.  A user could type `access_granted()` and the function would run same as if the user typed `24134231`.

```
import ast

def access_granted():
    print 'Yay'

while True:
    secret = 25134231
    user_input = raw_input('In: ')
    z = eval(user_input)
    if z == secret:
        access_granted()
```

Example:

```
In: access_granted()
Yay
In: 'Foo'

In: 25134231
Yay
```

Comment: Oh, I must have not express myself clearly :) I know that it's possible but I was wondering if there are some "dirty" tricks since it uses ast.literal_eval. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3641083 This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand everything.